# Fish not accepting commands: set: Warning: $PATH entry is not valid

Tags: path, ubuntu-16.04, fish

Something dumb happened. I tried to add something to the config.fish file to change the systemwide $PATH variable. I know, I probably should have read the documentation first, but I thought I know what I'm doing. Oh well.

To be more specific on what I did: I opened the config.fish file in /etc/fish and added the line `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/gradle-4.5.1/bin` to add gradle to my PATH-variable. Big mistake, because now my console won't accept anything anymore and I get the following whenever I open a console window: My question now: can I revert the change somehow without a console or is the only solution a reinstallation of my OS?

```
set: Warning: $PATH entry "/home/david/.local/bin" is not valid (Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden)
/usr/share/fish/functions/__fish_pwd.fish (Zeile 1): 
uname
^
Befehlsersetzungsblock
    called on line -1 of file /usr/share/fish/functions/__fish_pwd.fish

from sourcing file /usr/share/fish/functions/__fish_pwd.fish
    called on standard input

Befehlsersetzungsblock
    called on standard input

Befehlsersetzungsblock
    called on standard input

/usr/share/fish/functions/__fish_pwd.fish (Zeile 1): switch: Erwartete genau ein Argument, erhielt 0

switch (uname)
       ^
from sourcing file /usr/share/fish/functions/__fish_pwd.fish
    called on standard input

Befehlsersetzungsblock
    called on standard input

Befehlsersetzungsblock
    called on standard input

fish: 
echo $_ " "; __fish_pwd
             ^
Befehlsersetzungsblock
    called on standard input

~/.config/fish/functions/fish_greeting.fish (Zeile 1): 
set fish_greeting | figlet -f lean "Hi  David"
                    ^
Unbekannte Funktion 'fish_greeting'
    called on line 142 of file /usr/share/fish/functions/__fish_config_interactive.fish

Unbekannte Funktion '__fish_config_interactive'
    called on line 216 of file /usr/share/fish/config.fish

Unbekannte Funktion '__fish_on_interactive'
    called on standard input

in event handler: handler for generic event 'fish_prompt'

Befehl »tty« ist unter »/usr/bin/tty« verfügbar
Der Befehl konnte nicht gefunden werden, weil »/usr/bin« nicht Teil der Umgebungsvariable PATH ist.
tty: Befehl nicht gefunden.
~/.config/fish/functions/fish_prompt.fish (Zeile 3): 
    tty | string match -q -r tty
    ^
Unbekannte Funktion 'fish_prompt'
    called on standard input

Befehlsersetzungsblock
    called on standard input

Befehl »hostname« ist unter »/bin/hostname« verfügbar
Der Befehl konnte nicht gefunden werden, weil »/bin« nicht Teil der Umgebungsvariable PATH ist.
hostname: Befehl nicht gefunden.
/usr/share/fish/functions/prompt_hostname.fish (Zeile 1): 
hostname | string split '.'
^
Befehlsersetzungsblock
    called on line -1 of file /usr/share/fish/functions/prompt_hostname.fish

from sourcing file /usr/share/fish/functions/prompt_hostname.fish
    called on line 2 of file ~/.config/fish/functions/fish_prompt.fish

Befehlsersetzungsblock
    called on line 0 of file ~/.config/fish/functions/fish_prompt.fish

Befehlsersetzungsblock
    called on line 0 of file ~/.config/fish/functions/fish_prompt.fish

Unbekannte Funktion 'fish_prompt'
    called on standard input

Befehlsersetzungsblock
    called on standard input

Befehl »sed« ist unter »/bin/sed« verfügbar
Der Befehl konnte nicht gefunden werden, weil »/bin« nicht Teil der Umgebungsvariable PATH ist.
sed: Befehl nicht gefunden.
~/.config/fish/functions/fish_prompt.fish (Zeile 1): 
pwd|sed "s=$HOME=~="
    ^
Befehlsersetzungsblock
    called on line 0 of file ~/.config/fish/functions/fish_prompt.fish

Unbekannte Funktion 'fish_prompt'
    called on standard input

Befehlsersetzungsblock
    called on standard input

Befehl »date« ist unter »/bin/date« verfügbar
Der Befehl konnte nicht gefunden werden, weil »/bin« nicht Teil der Umgebungsvariable PATH ist.
date: Befehl nicht gefunden.
~/.config/fish/functions/fish_prompt.fish (Zeile 1): 
date +%X
^
Befehlsersetzungsblock
    called on line 0 of file ~/.config/fish/functions/fish_prompt.fish

Unbekannte Funktion 'fish_prompt'
    called on standard input

Befehlsersetzungsblock
    called on standard input

__fish_pwd: Befehl nicht gefunden.
fish: 
echo $_ " "; __fish_pwd
             ^
Befehlsersetzungsblock
    called on standard input
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> can I revert the change somehow without a console or is the only solution a reinstallation of my OS?

A reinstall is complete overkill.

Fish should still accept commands, it's just that there are so many commands in your prompt and such that it's hard to *see* the output.

Thankfully $PATH on many Linux distributions is quite simple, with most applications in /usr/bin. So `set -gx PATH /usr/bin` should get you to a state where you can edit config.fish to remove your mistake.

Or you could use absolute paths in the fish command, e.g. `/usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/nano /etc/fish/config.fish` should open nano with your config.fish.

Or you can open your config.fish in a graphical text editor that has the capability to edit root-owned files (e.g. Kate just asks for your password once you try to save)

Or you can change the "shell" or "profile" setting in your terminal - they don't need to open your users configured shell, they can also usually open an arbitrary program, like a different shell.

Comment: Thank you for your help! The solution with opening `nano` via it's path solved my problem and I've learned my lesson I guess: always check with the docs before trying something new. Again, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You don't use bash syntax in the fish config files. In fish, variables contain **lists** of values. The PATH variable is not a colon-separated string.

You want to do this instead to append a directory to the list:

```
set PATH $PATH /usr/local/gradle-4.5.1/bin
```

See https://fishshell.com/docs/current/tutorial.html#tut_path

Comment: That's what I've learned after checking the docs for fish. I guess I learned my lesson, and will check them now BEFORE I try something. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 2):

What you didn't realize, or temporarily forgot, is that in fish `PATH` is actually an array. It is not a single colon separated string of directories like it is in bash. And in fish when you concatenate an array to another string you get a cartesian product. Let's say you first did `export PATH=/dir1:/dir2` (using the bash notation). In fish that is equivalent to `set -gx PATH /dir1 /dir2`, an array var with two elements. Now do this

```
for x in PATH=$PATH:/dir3
    echo $x
end
```

What do you think will be echoed? This will be echoed:

```
PATH=/dir1:/dir3
PATH=/dir2:/dir3
```

And that is why your `PATH` is now more or less useless when you login.

The errors are from your `fish_prompt` function because it can't find any of the commands it needs to construct your prompt. But you should still be able to enter commands. Try setting your path to sane value. Just copy/paste this:

```
set -gx PATH /bin /usr/bin /usr/local/bin
```

That should make most of the commands you use accessible again. If your editor isn't in one of those directories include its directory as well. Now you should be able to edit your *config.fish* file.

P.S., Don't use the `export` command in fish. It's just a function that acts as a thin wrapper around `set`. You'll be better off in the long run learning to do it the fish way.

Comment: I noticed that most of them come from the `fish_prompt` function. And I learned about the `PATH` in fish now as well. I guess I'll remember that for a long time. Thank you for your input!